ZKTeco K40 attendance device DHCP issue
For a while now this attendance device has had this issue, where after a while of being inactive (no pinging was done towards it or anyone trying to connect), it enters some sort of "sleep" mode and you can't connect to it when it is connected to the local network and has internet access.
When I go to the Ethernet settings on the device, I see that DHCP is ON but all the other parameters are set to 0 (IP, Subnet mask and Default gateway). Now if I turn it OFF they reset back to normal (how they usually are set and are not 0). In both of the cases I can't ping the device..
I wonder if anyone has encountered the same issue with this attendance device and if there is any possible fix to it? Is it a firmware bug? Or is this just how it works?
I have tried resetting the DHCP ON and OFF but it does not seem to work..

That's not a DHCP issue. The two things you mention (inability to DHCP and inability to answer pings with static IP) add together and suggest that the device is unable to send and/or receive any packets at all – might be cable or ethernet port issue, etc. If you enable DHCP on it and then run a packet capture (wireshark/tcpdump) or look at the DHCP server's logs, does that show the device at least sending out DHCPDISCOVER packets? (e.g. our router would show "Offered" in the lease list.) And if you disable DHCP and set a static IP, does it answer ARP (show up in arp -a after ping attempt)?

Ok, thank you. It wasnt connected to the network so we fixed it, but the main issue is this. DHCP is turned ON on the device and the DNS is set, it has IP - all is set. But after some time (a couple of hours), when I try to ping it at the previously set IP I get that it can't be reached. When I go to the device itself in the Settings -> Ethernet I see that the IP is reset and its back to 0.0.0.0 but DHCP is still ON..That is the main issue at hand and I wonder why is it happening..
